# MySQL - Get record by category randomly and also have limit of every category

Tags: php, mysql

Still i am querying this for getting the result with 3 specific categories

```
SELECT
    id,
    title,
    category
FROM
    contents
WHERE
    category IN ('kids', 'adult', 'family')
LIMIT 10
```

[image]

But how i get the 4 kids, 3 adult and 3 family categories type row from our records like have in screenshot

[image]

please help me to solve this issue, there is dummy data and table structure. Thanks in advance

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for content
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `content`;
CREATE TABLE `content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of content
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('1', 'a', 'kids');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('2', 'b', 'kids');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('3', 'c', 'kids');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('4', 'd', 'kids');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('5', 'e', 'kids');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('6', 'f', 'kids');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('7', 'g', 'kids');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('8', 'h', 'kids');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('9', 'i', 'kids');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('10', 'j', 'kids');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('11', 'k', 'family');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('12', 'l', 'family');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('13', 'm', 'family');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('14', 'n', 'family');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('15', 'n', 'adult');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('16', '0', 'adult');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('17', 'p', 'adult');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('18', 'q', 'adult');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('19', 'r', 'adult');
INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('20', 's', 'adult');
```

Comment: Put your content table structure with test data.

Comment: @PrakashSaini Please have a look question again, added in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit each category separately and `UNION` the results.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, title, category
      FROM content
      WHERE category = 'kids'
      LIMIT 4
) kids
UNION SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, title, category
    FROM content
    WHERE category = 'adult'
    LIMIT 3
) adult
UNION SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, title, category
    FROM content
    WHERE category = 'family'
    LIMIT 3
) family
```

[Here's the Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9681dd/5).

Comment: Thanks for your replay, i have also in my mind about union.

Comment: You're right @aLvEe; that query won't work. You have to hack it a bit; I've updated the answer and this time I tested it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9681dd/5.